# How to get element's raw value without trimming it using dom4j?

Tags: dom4j

Imagine that I have the following XML element with multi-lines value `\nline2`,

```
<address>
line2</address>
```

I'm using dom4j [Element](https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.1.3/org/dom4j/Element.html)'s getText(), but it trimmed the empty line (the \n) and returned `line2`.

Is there a way to retrieve the raw value `\nline2` without trimming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that. You probably used getTextTrim().